# How to import something using IMPORTXML to google sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to import the following "item-id" to my google sheets

[Image of the developer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D45Vp.png)

how can i do this?

Comment: share the url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only we can see through your minimal image ...

```
=importxml(url,"//div/@item-id")
```